# Is it possible to record console gameplay with PC

Tags: pc, recording, nintendo-gamecube, sega-genesis

don't know if I am asking in the right place but would appreciate help, I want to record the gameplay from my sega megadrive and gamecube using a PC.I have the software to screen record my PC screen but don't know if there is a way to display the console output within the windows screen so that I can record it, or if it is possible to record between TV sources.

Answer (score 1):

You would need some kind of capture card device in your PC which you would plug your console into.  This used to be a really complicated thing but now there are awesome dedicated devices like this one
http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/game-capture/default.html

Unless your PC has some way to do video in with a capture device this will not be possible.

Comment: thanks for the response but I might see if I can get one if there is no other way to screen record  without buying one of these

Comment: That will not be possible unless you have hardware in your pc that allows you to capture video unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, also while I wait to buy one of these some day do you know a good website where i can download an emulator roms without the risk of viruses as my computer is pretty much naked to any sort of virus as I have no protection software and every site I have found looks very shady.

Answer (score -2):

Console have builtin support for screen capturing and publishing so you do not need a pc or any device to do so.

As you have not said which console you are using i cannot exactly say how to but you can go to console's setting and check that.

Comment: Maybe read the question again, he clearly said he has an sega megadrive and a gamecube.

Comment: Sadly, the Sega Megadrive is not equipped for screen capture or internet uploads.

Comment: ohh then it must be my mistake. Sorry.